# TextEdit app always opens with File Open dialog

Tags: textedit

Every time I open my TextEdit app it starts with the File Open dialog open.

How do I stop this?

Comment: This has irritated me forever - your question prompted me to actually have a look for how to fix it. Invicta just beat me to it, so +1 for everybody :)

Comment: What OS? Could you also provide the screenshot?

Comment: Yosemite - 10.10.1 (14B25). And it's simply the File Open dialog.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find this behaviour irritating too. I believe Mountain Lion introduced a new Open dialog to provide the option to save a new file in iCloud so that it’s available from other iOS devices. You can disable this feature by going to System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive Options then untick TextEdit.app and any other apps that have a similar behaviour.

Comment: That fixes it. It's beyond irritating. It's a bug.

Comment: This solution works for the same problem with QuickTime, too.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution **doesn't** work for Script Editor (at least on Monterey) – even though the solution **did** work for Text Edit. Any ideas?

Comment: save my days. It works for me in macOS 13.2

Comment: The path is slightly different (of course) with Ventura: System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options. Just one extra button to click is all.